# The Original Proofs of The Stable Manifold Theorem

Tags: reference-request, differential-equations

The book "Differential Equations and Dynamical Systems" by Lawrence Perko says that the first proofs of the Stable Manifold Theorem are from Hadamard in 1901, Perron in 1928, and Liapunov and Perron. I am trying to find these proofs.

Comment: References seem to be given in Perko (3/e).  You might include them for the convenience of others who might try to locate them....

Comment: Hadamard J.,  Sur l’itération et les solutions asymptotiques des équations différentielles, Bul. Soc. Math. de France 29 (1901), 224–8, transl. in  Springer Lecture Notes in Mathematics (book series(LNM, volume 2164), online?